# How to make slimes attack other entities

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know there is a way to make mobs attack each other by summoning an arrow with the target mob UUID on top of the mob you want to attack it, but it does not seem to work with slimes for some reason, does anyone have ideas on how to make it work?

The commands I'm using are as follows:

As soon as I detect when a player hits an entity, if there are any entities with the tag "summoned" I run this function

```
scoreboard players set @a playerdidhit 0
execute as @e[tag=summoned] at @s run data merge entity @s {AngerTime:0}
tag @e[tag=Hurt] add Target
tag @e[tag=Target] remove Hurt
```

```
execute as @e[tag=summoned] at @s run summon arrow ~ ~4 ~ {Motion:[0.0,-1.0,0.0],damage:0,life:1200}
execute as @e[tag=summoned] at @s run data modify entity @e[type=arrow,limit=1,sort=nearest] Owner set from entity @e[tag=Target,sort=nearest,limit=1] UUID
execute as @e[tag=summoned] at @s run data merge entity @s {AngerTime:1000000}
```

It works with other entities such as skeletons, blazes, zombies, spiders, but for some reason slimes don´t seem to care, is there a way to make this work?